# Couldn't find an AF_INET address of []

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a ROS node to subscribe to the topics from a rosbag

`/sensors/velodyne_points   /sensors/camera/image_color   /sensors/camera/camera_info`

Some excerpts from the code below:

```
// ROS includes
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
...
 
// OpenCV includes
...
 
// Include pcl
...
 
// Include PointCloud2 ROS message
...
 
static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";
const tf::TransformListener tf_listener_;
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel cam_model_;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
std::vector <tf::Vector3> objectPoints;
tf::Vector3 pt_cv;
std::vector <cv::Point3d> pt_transformed;
 
void processCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& info_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pointCloudMsg)
{
    ...
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "lidar_calibration");

ros::NodeHandle nh;
// ROS_INFO("Starting LiDAR node");

message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image_sub(nh, "image", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> info_sub(nh, "camera_info", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> lidar_sub(nh, "velodyne_points", 1);
message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sync(image_sub, info_sub, lidar_sub, 10);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&processCallback, _1, _2, _3));

ros::spin();
// cv::destroyWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);

return 0;

}
```

And my ROS variables are:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_MAVEN_DEPLOYMENT_REPOSITORY=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven
ROS_MAVEN_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY=https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_IP=localhost
ROS_HOME=/home/ak/.ros
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

I'm able to build the code but I'm stuck with the error when I rosrun the binary

```
[FATAL] [1525151060.907371740]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
[ERROR] [1525151060.944339461]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [:0].  Retrying...
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
Couldn't find an AF_INET address for []
```

And yes, I'm running `roscore` in another terminal and `bashrc` is sourced in every terminal session that is running.

The other posts in the forum which look similar are quite different than in my case.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290100/couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-of-%5B%5D/) by [reverse3D](https://answers.ros.org/users/31101/reverse3d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-01**:
Do you have any global variables that are ROS types? Something like a `ros::Time` or other object?

**Comment by [reverse3D](https://answers.ros.org/users/31101/reverse3d/) on 2018-05-01**:
No there are none with ros as global variables. This pastebin has the complete  [code](https://pastebin.com/XkeivXym)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a ROS type and it internally initialises other ROS types:

```
const tf::TransformListener tf_listener_;
```

I'm almost certain that is the cause of the error you are seeing. If you want to keep it in the global scope, you could use a pointer and initialise that in your `main(..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [reverse3D](https://answers.ros.org/users/31101/reverse3d/) on 2018-05-01**:
@gvdhoorn You are right. That was the problem. I somehow overlooked it. Thanks